# How to filter data in both directions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to filter data in both directions?

I have data that I receive from the server and store in the state, I need to filter it to open and close, but since I update the state I can only close it, but how can I then open it ***using only the state***?

```
const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Project 01",
    project_id: null,
    is_project: true,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "Task 01",
    project_id: 1,
    is_project: false,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "Task 02",
    project_id: 1,
    is_project: false,
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    title: "Project 02",
    project_id: null,
    is_project: true,
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    title: "Task 03",
    project_id: 4,
    is_project: false,
  },
];

const [state, setState] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setState(data); // my fetch req
  }, []);

  const onVisible = (id) => {
    const filtered = state?.filter((el) => el?.project_id !== id);
    setState(filtered);
  };
```

[image]

When I click on +, the tasks disappear, but if I click on + again they will not appear again, since I am using a state, how can I make them appear again?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/elegant-mestorf-7m4szc?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A7%2C24

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to save whether the values are expanded or not. Let say if you can modify the data before storing it into response then you can introduce a new key called `is_expanded` to indicated whether to show it as expanded.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Project 01",
    project_id: null,
    is_project: true,
    is_expanded: true,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "Task 01",
    project_id: 1,
    is_project: false,
    is_expanded: true,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "Task 02",
    project_id: 1,
    is_project: false,
    is_expanded: true,
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    title: "Project 02",
    project_id: null,
    is_project: true,
    is_expanded: true,
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    title: "Task 03",
    project_id: 4,
    is_project: false,
    is_expanded: true,
  },
];

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setState(data); // my fetch req
  }, []);

  const onVisible = (id) => {
    // const filtered = state?.filter((el) => el?.project_id !== id);
    setState((prevValue) => {
      const newValue = [];
      prevValue.forEach((value) => {
        if (value.id === id || value.project_id === id) {
          newValue.push({
            ...value,
            is_expanded: !value.is_expanded,
          });
        } else {
          newValue.push(value);
        }
      });
      return newValue;
    });
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {state?.map((el) => (
        <div key={el.id} style={{ display: "flex", columnGap: 8 }}>
          {el?.is_project && (
            <div onClick={() => onVisible(el?.id)}>+ {el.title}</div>
          )}
          {!el?.is_project && el?.is_expanded && (
            <div style={{ marginLeft: el?.is_project ? 0 : 24 }}>
              {el.title}
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Initially, all of them are expanded. Once you toggle any project, any value that is part of it or the project will be toggled.

Comment: You are my God!

Answer (score 0):

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Project 01",
    project_id: null,
    is_project: true,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "Task 01",
    project_id: 1,
    is_project: false,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "Task 02",
    project_id: 1,
    is_project: false,
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    title: "Project 02",
    project_id: null,
    is_project: true,
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    title: "Task 03",
    project_id: 4,
    is_project: false,
  },
];

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setState(data); // my fetch req
  }, []);

  const onVisible = (id) => {
    const filtered = state?.filter((el) => el?.project_id !== id);
    console.log(state, filtered);
    if (state.length == filtered.length) {
      setState(data);
    } else {
      setState(filtered);
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {state?.map((el) => (
        <div key={el.id} style={{ display: "flex", columnGap: 8 }}>
          {el?.is_project && <div onClick={() => onVisible(el?.id)}>+</div>}
          <div style={{ marginLeft: el?.is_project ? 0 : 24 }}>{el.title}</div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

this is a temporary solution , the whole mapping of the data part is a bit unclear .